# Type guard unsoundly narrows union type in else branch

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I've noticed type guards applied to union types narrow the else branch in a potentially unsound way.

```
const isShortString = (value: any): value is string => {
  return typeof value === 'string' && value.length < 10;
}

const fn1 = (value: string | number) => {
   if (isShortString(value)) {
      // ✅ Correctly narrowed to string
      return value.trim();
   } else {
      // ❌ Incorrectly narrowed to `number` (This could still be a string with length < 10)
      return value.toExponential();
   }
}
```

TS handles it well with native type guards; or I guess more accurately when checking a "type guard" `&&` "some other condition".

```
const fn2 = (value: string | number) => {
   if (typeof value === 'string' && value.length < 10) {
      // ✅ Correctly narrowed to `string`
      return value.trim();
   } else {
      // ✅ Correctly remains `string | number`
      return value.toExponential(); // Error
   }
}
```

Is there a way to express that `isShortString` shouldn't narrow the else branch or is this a misuse of type guards?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAygCxAJyoqa5gOYwC8MAFAG4CGANgK4CmAXDBWAJ4CUTltd8EM0HPiIA+GAG8AsACgYMNHSg00YGFFYAHOiABmMbvSKFiAckG48JmADJr+6vQB0VOvijIYAHhgBGAAwA3DIAvjIyAPThMABCFAAmMqCQsDpgPkSkBowC2BYwAD4wYDQAtgBGdGjsohIycvB6JAgo6Ji5+OQOdOzVUrL1cpEwgKDkMADC6ArAUFSsRRRoaCAA7nRxaiA5Qnh1A-KKyqpZjrklJOxB-TDBMHRUELx9ezBDgDLkMACSYKCLdNOz80WKzWGxgAANiuVKmDSAAVZAIGCgGhUdbQOBUKgwCrMLZ5ZZwdwwFxuDzefzsXYDBRKFT2HgnEAAUQAHhpwK4oHBqOdLvVQtIBREogBxEAgBLSJLQGCpABMGU6PCY5mEhUhFSqNSecjgjXUWl09MMxlMqssNjsxxJeCJYgptSu9SGowmv3+czACyWq3WUE2YPNYKp9Rph2NdBOODOFypNzuD0dzxd40mfxmcwUJQouH4gfaBHVpU1wadcjDdOO-tZ7LAnO5VF5LyiTKBaDjIRkQA)

Comment: If you don't want it to be narrowed, then why is there a type predicate `value is string`?

Comment: This is a misuse of type guard functions; you're looking for "one-sided" type guard functions as requested in [ms/TS#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048).  The suggestion in there is to try to make your guarded type narrower than one of the union members, so not just `string`, but `string & ...` for something suitable.  In your case I'd probably do [this](//tsplay.dev/Wo5YaN).  Does that address your question and meet your needs?  If so, I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please @jcalz mention me, or I won't be notified).

Comment: @jcalz yes, that TS issue is exactly what I was looking for; it didn't come up in my searches so thank you! I need to read more but I think the solution suggested would work; in my real world use case, I don't necessarily know what else is being checked (e.g. length, odd / even, integer, regex etc.) but think I could still define some obscure optional field to stop the negative case from narrowing so please do write up the answer 

Comment: @kelly I do want it to be narrowed, but only in the positive case (if branch, not the else branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for "one-sided" [user-defined type guard funtions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048).

TypeScript doesn't currently support *negated types* (as implemented but never merged in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)) of the form `not T`.  But the *intent* of user-defined type guard functions whose return type is a type predicate of the form `v is T` is that a `true` return value should narrow `v` from its current type `V` to something like [the intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `V & T`, while a `false` return value should narrow `v` from its current type `V` to `V & not T`.  That is, these type guard functions are supposed to split `V` into the piece compatible with `T` and the piece that isn't.

So a function whose type is `(value: any) => value is string` should really be used to determine if `value` is or *is not* a `string`.  Hence you are misusing type guard functions.

---

If TypeScript ever directly supports "one-sided" functions, maybe you could write `(value: any) => (true & (value is string)) | false`.  Currently, though, since TypeScript lacks negated types, you can get similar behavior by changing your guarded type to something where there's no reasonable way to represent its negation.  With [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `string | number`, it's easy to split it into `string` or `number`.  But if you don't split at union boundaries, then the remainder is unrepresentable in TypeScript, and the compiler gives up on the `false` case.   For example, if you write `value is string & {prop: 123}`, then the `true` case can narrow from `string | number` to `string & {prop: 123}`.  But the `false` case can't narrow at all.  There's no `number | (string & not {prop: 123})` we can narrow to.  So it's still `string | number`.  This approach is mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048).

You could just use `string & {randomFakeProp: any}`.  But in your case there is a real structural difference between a "short" `string` and a regular one; the `length` property.  So you can write out something vaguely correct like this:

```
const isShortString = (
    value: any
): value is string &
{ length: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 } => {
    return typeof value === 'string' && value.length < 10;
}
```

After all, a short string has a `length` of some number between `0` and `9`, and we can write that as a union.  Now things behave more as desired:

```
const fn1 = (value: string | number) => {
    if (isShortString(value)) {
        return value.trim();
    } else {
        return value.toExponential(); // error!
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAygCxAJyoqa5gOYwC8MAFAFAyUwBuAhgDYCuApgFwy1gCeZAlO3SbN4EGNBz4YAMjIBvGPWb4oydgAYYAHxgBGLTABM+gMz6ALPoCs+gGz6A7PoAc+gJwwAvkQB8MWRSo0ZihGNDAYKC4AB2YQADMaBhYiQmIAcnFcPDTpKUShADpFZWQYAB5dNQBuMg8yMlBIWDiwPWISQRZ2TMltMEYAWwAjZjReHz8AyjgEkgQUdExsLI6k5l5x-yptmCCQsPyWAuWBkl4a7a9meghhLZ3KPdDwzuZjkABRAA8o8CUoOAMM5VGAAelBMFGaHQAEIpp5akA)

Comment: What would an opposite function, isLongString, look like with this approach? Would it even be representable?

Comment: I ended up using a nominal optional symbol property which, in my tests, encapsulates the hack quite nicely because IntelliSense doesn't have access to the symbol so doesn't try to autocomplete https://github.com/richardscarrott/ok-computer/blob/af8926c19503fe9c1ad5b600df1aafd2e422b100/src/ok-computer.ts#L121